# How do I use async await when a component leaves view

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

## How do I use Async Await ?

When this.props.onChangeStep1() is called, the component where the view is rendered is replaced by another component.

If the component has been swapped would Async Await still work ?

```
s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {

this.props.onChangeStep1(); //<----- After s3.upload I want to call this first 

            this.setState(   //<----But I want this to run in the background 
                                  // even though the component is not in view
                  {
                myState: "data-from-s3Upload"
              });
          }.bind(this)
        );
```

Comment: When you say "not in view" and "replaced by another component" do you mean it's actually unmounted? Or just hidden?

Comment: it's unmounted because...onChangeStep makes this component be swapped with another one

Comment: There is a re-render that takes place, and on the new re-render this component is left out

Comment: reading up on how this might help.. componentWillUnmount (){}

Comment: componentWillUnmount() is invoked immediately before a component is unmounted and destroyed. Perform any necessary cleanup in this method, such as invalidating timers, canceling network requests, or cleaning up any subscriptions that were created in componentDidMount().

You should not call setState() in componentWillUnmount() because the component will never be re-rendered. Once a component instance is unmounted, it will never be mounted again.

Comment: Not looking good

Comment: So when a component is unmounted, it is essentially lost. Even re-mounting it will give a _different_ instance of that component, in no way related to the other one. So you don't want to be setting the state of an unmounted component, cos it doesn't exist and would be lost anyway. If you want to keep the result then you need to lift the uploading functionality up to a higher component that isn't being unmounted and persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a callback is set to be executed later and the component that initiated the asynchronous call is unmounted, the callback will be executed regardless. If the callback attempts to act on the unmounted component (changing its state for instance) it will be considered as a memory leak and React will notify you with an error message in the console.

Comment: Thanks I did get that error, my fix to this problem was to forward all the logic back to the App.js component

Comment: this.props.onChangeStep1(event)

Answer (score 0):

```
this.props.onChangeStep1(e) // <-- Forward data and Process logic on App.js / Parent Component
```